Notation for vector density in Lagrangian density
Consider a manifold $M$ and a Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L} \equiv \mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla \phi)$. By varying the action, one obtains the equation
$$\int_M \, dV \; \Big( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} - \nabla_k \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_k \phi)} \Big) \delta \phi + \oint_{\partial M} \, dS \; \Big( n_k \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_k \phi} \Big) \delta \phi \enspace = \enspace0$$
The first term is the well-known Euler-Lagrange equation. I am interested in the "notational possibilities" of the second term. Now, calling
$$X^k := \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_k \phi}$$
Then I would at first assume, that the integrand in the second term may be written as
$$n_k X^k = g(\mathbf{n},\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{n^{\flat}}(\mathbf{X})$$
with the unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$. However, I have the feeling that this is not entirely correct, as

$X^k$ is not a vector, but rather a vector density. But the metric $g$ takes two vectors as arguments and not two vector densities. So the first equality is somewhat fishy.

Moreover, can one even write a vector density as $\mathbf{X} = X^k \partial_k$ or is writing it this way a flawed notation?

The covector $\mathbf{n}^{\flat}$ also acts on vectors and not on vector densities. Is the action on vector densities defined for a covector?



We can probably extend the meanings of these expressions to work with vector densities. The expression $n_k X^k$ would then result in a scalar density. But it might be more correct to instead include $dS$ with $n_k,$ $dS_k=n_k,dS,$ and consider the pairing $\langle \mathbf X, d\mathbf S\rangle=\langle X^k, dS_k\rangle$ instead of an inner product.
